# Changing the orientation of pyplot graph's x values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following data:

```
stage_summary = {'Day1': {'1': 100.0, '2': 0.0, '3': 0.0, '4': 0.0, '5': 0.0, '6': 0.0, '7': 0.0, '8': 0.0}, 'Day2': {'1': 100.0, '2': 0.0, '3': 0.0, '4': 0.0, '5': 0.0, '6': 0.0, '7': 0.0, '8': 0.0}, 'Day3': {'1': 89.8, '2': 10.2, '3': 0.0, '4': 0.0, '5': 0.0, '6': 0.0, '7': 0.0, '8': 0.0}, 'Day4': {'1': 58.6, '2': 41.4, '3': 0.0, '4': 0.0, '5': 0.0, '6': 0.0, '7': 0.0, '8': 0.0}, 'Day5': {'1': 52.71, '2': 47.06, '3': 0.0, '4': 0.0, '5': 0.0, '6': 0.23, '7': 0.0, '8': 0.0}, 'Day6': {'1': 47.89, '2': 50.65, '3': 0.0, '4': 0.0, '5': 0.0, '6': 1.46, '7': 0.0, '8': 0.0}, 'Day7': {'1': 49.72, '2': 46.95, '3': 0.0, '4': 0.0, '5': 0.0, '6': 3.33, '7': 0.0, '8': 0.0}, 'Day8': {'1': 52.59, '2': 39.35, '3': 0.0, '4': 0.0, '5': 0.0, '6': 8.05, '7': 0.0, '8': 0.01}, 'Day9': {'1': 55.45, '2': 30.73, '3': 0.0, '4': 0.0, '5': 0.0, '6': 13.74, '7': 0.0, '8': 0.08}} 

date_list = ['2019-05-28',
 '2019-05-29',
 '2019-05-30',
 '2019-05-31',
 '2019-06-03',
 '2019-06-04',
 '2019-06-05',
 '2019-06-06',
 '2019-06-07']
```

And I plot the data in this way, as a line graph:

```
for each_state in list(range(1,9)):
    tmp = []
    for each_day in stage_summary:
        tmp.append(stage_summary[each_day][str(each_state)])
    plt.plot(date_list, tmp, label=str('State ' + str(each_state)))
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.xlabel('Days')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

which results in the following graph,
[image]

However, as you can see, the x labels are dates, which are long strings. And therefore, it has to be rotated and be presented vertically to make it readable. But I am not sure how I can change the orientation of x values in a plotly graph. How can I do so?

Answer (score 2):

You are using matplotlib and not plotly, right?

If yes, try:

```
for each_state in list(range(1,9)):
    tmp = []
    for each_day in stage_summary:
        tmp.append(stage_summary[each_day][str(each_state)])
    plt.plot(date_list, tmp, label=str('State ' + str(each_state)))
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.xlabel('Days')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `plotly.graph_objs.Layout.xaxis.tickangle` = 90.

Detail: https://plot.ly/python/axes/#set-and-style-axes-title-labels-and-ticks

Comment: I am sorry, I use matplotlib pyplot, not plotly, edited it now